# ADB2C: set page layout while resetting password at the first login

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, change-password, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I successfully implemented the "password reset" after the first login (following [this readme](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon/readme.md), so as you can see I used the XML files for custom policies). It's working like a charm: the user is able to reset the password when she/he login for the first time. But there is a "cosmetic" issues: I would like to change the "page layout". At the moment I see a "gray cube":

[image]

How can I add a custom image in this section?
Thanks for your time and interest.

Comment: Try to see this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) to customize the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do basic UI customisation, like changing that icon
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Or full HTML customization:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: Ok, in my XML custom policy file called "TrustFrameworkBase.xml" I changed the item "api.localaccountpasswordreset" into the following one:

<ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset"> <LoadUri>https://link/to/the/customized/html</LoadUri> <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri> <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:selfasserted:1.1.0</DataUri> <Metadata> <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account change password page</Item> </Metadata> </ContentDefinition>

And it's working!! I can see my company brand instead of the ugly gray box :-)
Thank you!!